# How to implement BroadcastReceiver to do different tasks depends on time interval

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

My application needs to show some notifications for schedules (like Alarm), based on time interval.

For example:

There are 4 tasks I have setted in my application, like

```
Task A -> from 10:00 to 13:00
Task B -> from 15:10 to 16:00
Task C -> from 17:00 to 17:30
Task D -> from 20:00 to 23:30
```

So notification should be shown as

at 10:00 **Task A** *has started*

at 13:00 **Task A** *has ended*

at 15:10 **Task B** *has started*

... and so on.

How can I implement this? Can you please provide some tutorials related to it? 
And if there are more than one way, which is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [`TimerTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html)

And there is some code on how to use it:

http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/docs/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is this is the only way? Or this is the best way?

Comment: This is not the only way, but I think this is the best way for your requirements

Comment: One big confusion.. When Task A ends, after 2:10 hrs Task B will start, so do I need to create one timer which work between Task A end to Task B start? And Then I have to create another timer which will handle Task B start to Task B end. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, I think it should be like that